# How to add Hawtio plugins when running the standalone jar

Tags: hawtio

I run hawtio via the standalone jar and am not sure how to add plugins or if its even possible.

From the [docs](http://hawt.io/plugins/howPluginsWork.html) I understand the static linking and deployment unit when using a container like tomcat or jboss but not how to add plugins when running the standalone jar.

Is it possible to build the jar with the plugins or is the only way to use a webapp container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your custom plugins as a .war file to the classpath, when you run the standalone hawtio.

And for how to build a custom plugin, then check some of the examples here

- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-plugin-examples

Comment: I have logged a ticket to make this much easier out of the box: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1809

Comment: You can check the commit log for the code I did to include the custom plugins, you can wait for next release, or just build your own Main JAR that does this, just like the hawtio-app JAR does.

Comment: where to download the plugin war files?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't use static linking when you run the standalone .jar hawtio. Instead, you build the plugins as .war and put them into plugins folder

http://hawt.io/plugins/howPluginsWork.html - look at Separate Deployment Unit